# The system was running slow and reboot was useless

Tags: linux, operating-systems

My system was running slow, I checked the system with `top`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, `strace` and so on, but I could not find the issue. So I reboot the system but it was useless.

Then I shutdown the server, and restart it after a few minutes, and the system was normal.

Why reboot was useless, shutdown and restart was work?

(P.S. I test the system with command `time bc -l <<< "scale=1000; a(1);"`)

Comment: Not much for us to provide you with any sort of definitive answer to your problem.  You should do a lot more detective work analyzing logs and error messages during the process.

Comment: @mdpc My question was not why my system was running slow, it was why reboot was useless, shutdown and restart was work, what was the different between the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown actually shuts down most parts of the computer, where with reboot all the components are running. If you have hardware problems it could be, that the shutdown emptied some bad capacitors and after power on the system will work ok for a while.

Look for some bad capacitors on your motherboard. You can find some descriptions how to find them [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1102467-bad-capacitors-how-to-spot-them/)